# tableau, excel workbook, three worksheets, want data sources column in union

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I have a question on Tableau Desktop. I have an excel file with three tabs: Applications, Shared Drives, Sharepoint_Libraries. I would like to union all of these tables. I would like a column called Data Source with the below values. So from Applications excel file, I would like a Data Source column in the Union which says Applications. So from Shared Drives excel file, I would like a Data Source column in the Union which says Shared Drives. Lastly, from Sharepoint_Libraries excel file, I would like a Data Source column in the Union which says Sharepoint_Libraries. How can I do this in Tableau? Do I need to edit the source excel files and add the Data Source column in each file? Or, can I create a calculated field called Data Source and use a formula to populate this information?

| Data Source |
| --- |
| Applications |
| Shared Drives |
| Sharepoint_Libraries |

Comment: I think it'd be cleaner to go the excel route, better to edit data as far upstream as possible imo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tableau has a "merged mismatched fields" option for this situation.

So..

- open Desktop
- connect to the Excel file
- drag over the Applications sheet
- drag over the Shared Drives sheet and position it just below Applications until you see the "union" box appear then release your mouse button
- repeat for Sharepoint Libraries
- in the preview window (below) you will see the three different fields.
- highlight the three fields that you want to merge
- right-click and choose Merge Mismatched Fields.

Then you can rename the field accordingly :)